# SAS: Invalid Date/Time/Datetime constant Error

Tags: date, macros, sas

I'm trying to check if the value in the DOB field is greater than a given date. My code is parametrized by year of service. For instance, when I have the reference date as '31Dec2010'd, it works fine. But when part of it contains a reference to another macro variable, I get an error message.

`%let yos = 2010;`
and inside a data step, I have
`if date_of_birth > '31Dec&yos.'d` ... some code follows. Then I get the following error message: "invalid date/time/datetime constant `'31Dec&yos.'d`.

Any ideas,
Thanks

Comment: Hi, your issue is answered in the duplicate question linked (see top).  You need to use " (double quotes) not ' (single quotes).  Please leave additional information if your problem is not related to this.

Comment: Thanks. Using double quotes instead of single quotes fixed the problem.